# jsc - invoke non-javascript program?

Tags: javascript

I'm considering using javascript as glue code instead of a traditional Unix shell for my programs because javascript has some really elegant constructs. But for heavy-lifting, I want to continue using other languages (e.g. java).

Is there a way to execute a child process that is not written in javascript? Something like:

```
#!/bin/jsc

# Neither of these work
load('test.sh');
run('test.sh');
```

I know I could use nodejs but I really want to enforce core javascript in my code (because I may wish to copy pieces of it into browser javascript files).

Comment: *"I know I could use nodejs but I really want to enforce core javascript in my code"* – what is *"core javascript"*? nodejs uses a javascript implementation (v8) the same way browsers do (chrome v8, firefox spidermonkey)

Comment: if you want to write scripts in JavaScript, use node; it comes with the [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module that can do exactly what your'e asking

Comment: @naomik - I'm guessing Node.js is some external community to the V8 engine. By "core" I mean the "official" javascript shell that is inseparable from the javascript language runtime (so I am not at the mercy of Node.js's future). Or is `jsc` no more "official" than `node.js`?

Comment: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat there is no *"official javascript shell that is inseparable from the javascript language runtime"* because there is no *"official javascript shell"* nor is there an* "official javascript language runtime"* – there is [Standard ECMA-262](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) which is the language specification for ECMA 2017 – anyone can implement ECMA, and the v8 team (as well as others) have done a fantastic job in keeping implementation features on par with the ever-evolving ECMA specification

Comment: [https://node.green](http://node.green/) is a good place to see the current implementation status of these features in node

Comment: @naomik Thank you for explaining that to me in detail, please post as an answer so I can give you proper credit.

Comment: My only remaining questions are why is `jsc` shipped as part of Mac OS X (which made me consider it more "official") but node.js isn't? And also maybe I'd like to know is there a reason why `jsc` has no way to execute a native shell command (my guess is simply not many people use it so there's never been a push to implement it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to @naomik from the comments section:

> there is no "official javascript shell that is inseparable from the
>   javascript language runtime" because there is no "official javascript
>   shell" nor is there an* "official javascript language runtime"* –
>   there is Standard ECMA-262 which is the language specification for
>   ECMA 2017 – anyone can implement ECMA, and the v8 team (as well as
>   others) have done a fantastic job in keeping implementation features
>   on par with the ever-evolving ECMA specification